# Where is Ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386

Tags: installation, cd-image

I accidentally downloaded the server version of 11.10 but need the client desktop version to run on my windows machine. I already have a VMWare player. But, I just cant seem to find it on download area. I saw Ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent but I dont think that's the one.
Thnx

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=latest) should do the trick.

I found the link @ ubuntu.com/download.

Comment: Thnx, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download via torrent: [.torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)

Comment: Ah! didn't realize it will work. Thnx.